# How does one view the SQL query that a button fires in Access?

Tags: ms-access

There is an existing Access program that I need to learn more about.  There is a button in the program that, when pressed, outputs an Excel file.  It queries some tables within it for the data.

How would I view the raw SQL code that this button utilizes to generate this Excel file?  From the button's properties, I can see that its On Click event is "[Embedded Macro]".  Also, it's object type is "Query".

Thank you in advance.

---

In the On Click row (under the Event tab in Properties), when I click on the ellipse next to "[Embedded Macro]", I am presented with an expandable section containing these rows:

Object Type - Query
Object Name - Inv File Query
Output Format - Excel Workbook (*.xlsx)
Output File - (blank)
Auto Start - No
Template File - (blank)
Encoding - (blank)
Output Quality - Print

I don't see any logic (SQL, VBA, etc.) listed anywhere, however, as to how Access will construct this Excel file that it exports.  How would I view this logic?  I figure this logic has to be stored somewhere because the button does actually return an Excel file populated with data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the name of the query used here.

The SQL thus used is in a query called **Inv File Query**.

So you need to display the query objects in the nav pane (assuming 2007 onwards).

So choose this:

[image]

And then all of the queries used in the application will display. If the query Inv File Query does not show, it may be hidden. (to be fair, I would choose All Access objects - but for this we choose query). And hit F11 if the nav pane does not show.

If for some reason you  STILL do not see the query, then you want to display hidden objects.

To display all hidden objects then right click on the top part of the nav pane (on the query) like this:

[image]

Then:
Turn all of the options, and now you should be able to see/view the SQL used for the query called Inv File Query

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. Open the form in Design view
2. Open the Properties sheet by right-clicking on the button and choosing "Properties".
3. In the On Click event, where you see "[Embedded Macro]", click on the ellipse on the far right

As a pointer, once you've figured out what's going on, I'd do my best to convert it all to VBA code.  This will eliminate confusion in the future, and macros are really the poor man's way out of writing code anyway.  I never, *ever* use macros in my Access apps.

Comment: Thanks for all of the information.  When I perform these steps, I am presented with an expandable section with these rows: "Object Type", "Object Name", etc.  I don't see any logic (SQL, or otherwise), however.

Comment: Also, I just updated this post's body with more details as to what I see.

Comment: Yes.  If the original programmer knew SQL or code logic, he/she probably would have written it.  What you need to do is pick apart that macro piece by piece.  There's no code behind it, but most (if not all) macro logic has a corresponding VBA command.  You have to translate, which is why I suggested just rewriting it in VBA once you figure out what's going on.

Comment: OK, if it's Object Type is a query, then there's a query in your DB with the same name as what's entered in the Object Name field.

Comment: Ok, I've got the database file open now.  On the left-hand side of the screen, there is an "All Tables" section listed.  I see the tables, but not any queries anywhere.  It looks like each table in this section is expanded.

Comment: Odd: in the Create tab, when I click on the Query Design button, a popup appears that contains tabs for Tables, Queries, and Both.  Under the Queries tab, however, nothing is listed.